# Do we know why each of the misfits is in the misfit classs?

Tags: welcome-to-demon-school-iruma-kun

For some of the students, it's kind of easy to guess why they're in the misfit class, like with Jazz; but others, like Keroli Crocell, not so much. There are also some we specifically enumerated in the story, such as with Iruma and Asmodeus's fight, but I cannot recall if it is specifically explained why all the others are in there.

Do we know the specific reason each of them are in the misfit class? Could I get a list of the reasons? With references to when in the story it's learned, if possible (if there were an episode where it's summarized, for instance, that would be great to know).

Comment: I have a very vague recollection that Keroli got herself into the Misfit Class deliberately, possibly related to her activities as an idol, but I might just be making that up.